# Employee Department Relationship in Database

Tags: database-design, relational

I'm designing a relational database for SCM (as part of designing information system for the enterprise). But when it came to the relationship between the employee and its department, I had some troubles .

I designed the following entities :

- `Employee` ( **ID** , Fname , Mname , Lname , Sex , Phone , Address , Hiring date , .. etc )
- `Department` ( **ID** , name )

and since the relation is one-to-many (every employee should work for - and only one - dept., while every dept has many employees), I added `Department ID` to the attributes of the `Employee`. But the problem is how to represent a `MANAGE` relationship (one-to-one).

Is it valid to design a new relation that we call : `Employee_manage_Department` and its attributes are (`Employee ID , Department ID`) where both columns are part of the primary key ??

thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-nov/o61sql-512018.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but as the roles of an Employee in the company has limited (life)time, I would add two new DateTime collumns, DATE_FROM and DATE_TO, making the DATE_FROM part of the composed primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Since manager-department relationship is 1:1, you can simply add a `Manager ID` to the department table, which would act as a foreign key referencing the employee table:

[image]

This introduces a circular dependency, preventing the insertion of new data, which can be resolved in one of the following ways:

- Defer one of the circular FKs (if the DBMS supports it).
- Make `Manager ID` NULL-able. You may need to do it anyway in case you need to support the concept of manager-less department.

BTW, this allows for a department to be managed by an employee from a different department. If that is undesirable, you'll need to use an identifying relationship so the *same* department ID can propagate back and forth:

[image]

---

NOTE: The separate `Employee_manage_Department` table would be appropriate for modeling M:N relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The `Employee.department_id` should be a `foreign_key` to the `Department` table and be unique and non-null. That satisfies your constraints of `One Employee has one department` and `One department can have many employees`

Answer (score 0):

No i don't see this as necessary if an employee will and can only belong to a single department but if an employee can have more than one department then you can go ahead ... on a second thought if you would like to keep the from and the exit date of the staff i think you can

Comment: Yes.....omoabobade is right. Though the relation with a composite primary key (emplyee ID, Department ID) is valid, but it is not required here at all.

Answer (score 0):

Is the manager of a departement always one of the employees who work in that department?  If the answer is yes, then a boolean MnagerFlag in the Employee table should be sufficient.

You will need to declare a constraint or enforce a rule that prevents more than one employee in a depratment from having this flag set.